# Vue.JS countdown not works

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue application, but the countdown not work good.
Actually i dont know why.

View `{{ $parent.timer }}` i see the good value.

Vue data:

```
data: function() {
      return {
         timer : 3,
...
```

and here is my countdown function:

```
countdown : function(time,callback)
    {
         //time is equal 5
        this.timer = time;
        //this.timer is equal 5
        var timerInterval = undefined;

        timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if(this.timer == 1) {
                this.timer = 0;
                callback();
                return clearInterval(timerInterval);
            }
            // First time undefined, in 2nd is NaN
            this.timer -= 1;
            // NaN
        }, 1000);
    }
```

call function:

```
this.countdown(data.time,function(){ //smtng });
```

What i do bad? Its work in my older Vue application.

I hope someone can help to me :)
Thanks so much!

Comment: Use `setInterval(() => { ... }`, so that your `this` is the scope you want it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an issue with scope of `this`, as explained below:

`function() {...}` creates a new scope inside. If you use `this` inside this function, it does not refer to outer scope. Therefore your `this.timer` of Vue component does not get updated from inside your `setInterval()`.

`() => {...}` works like a function but does not create a new scope inside.

Check if the following code works:

```js
timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if(this.timer == 1) {
        this.timer = 0;  // `this` points to the scope of Vue component
        callback();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}, 1000);
```

More info on arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions