# How to update data of a VueJS instance from a jQuery AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js

I have a VueJS instance with some data :

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        id: '',
        name: {
            firstname: "", 
            lastname: "", 
            country: "", 
            valueset: false
        },
// ...
```

In my HTML, I also have :

```
<input class="id" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" v-model.lazy="id" v-on:change="create_casenr">
```

Therefore after filling up this field, the method `create_casenr` of my instance is triggered.

```
create_casenr: function(event) {
    // update the full name of user
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://elk.example.com:9200/users/user/' + this.id
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.name = data._source;
        this.name.valueset = true;
        console.log(this.name);
    })
// ...
```

What happens is that :

- `create_casenr` is called upon the change in the field (OK)
- the AJAX call goes through successfully, I see the expected output on the console for both `data`and `this.name` (OK)
- **but** `name` is not updated in the instance of VueJS.

I can see it is not updated because other parts of my code which rely on it do not see it; I also checked with the VueJS Chrome add-on and all the variables are correctly set (including `id`), except for `name`.

**Is there a specific way I should address the data of a VueJS instance when modified via a jQuery AJAX call?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a scope issue of `this.name` in your AJAX success handler.

The `this.name` inside is not the same as `this.name` in your Vue component. So your name is not getting set in the Vue component.

You may use arrow functions to get around this issue:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://elk.example.com:9200/users/user/' + this.id
    }).done(data => {
        this.name = data._source;  // 'this' points to outside scope
        this.name.valueset = true;
    });
```

Similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40200989/654825

More info on Arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: For future readers: the arrow function is not supported by IE as of October 2016 (and probably will never be as IE 11 is the last IE). Edge, Chrome, Firefox do work.

Comment: Yes, IE11 does not support arrow functions. But when use vue-cli to make a production build, babel compiler takes care of converting arrow functions to ES5 compatible code. So you can still use arrow functions, but do the entire development in Chrome / Firefox, and final testing in IE11.

Comment: Thank you - I did not know about vue-cli.

Answer (score 10):

not same scope for `this.name`

```
create_casenr: function(event) {
// update the full name of user
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://elk.example.com:9200/users/user/' + this.id
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    this.name = data._source;
    this.name.valueset = true;
    console.log(this.name);
}.bind(this))
```

add a `bind(this)`

Comment: It looks like `.bind()` is deprecated in jQuery 3 and discouraged earlier (according to http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: @WoJ : it's bind ES5.1 function to bind internal this of anonymous function, see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind and it's not deprecated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that plays a role here is how Vue.js updates the DOM.  For details read this section in the documentation: [Async Update Queue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue)

In short use "nexTick" callback to process your code after Vue.js is done updating the DOM.

```
methods: {
   someMethod() {
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://...',
      }).done(function (data) {
        self.a = data.a;
        self.b = data.b;
        self.$nextTick(function () {
           // a and b are now updated
        }
      });
   }
}
```